# Bayes estimator, sample is uniform and prior is Gamma

Tags: probability, solution-verification, statistical-inference, bayesian, parameter-estimation

**This is for a personal review:** $X_i\sim U(0,\theta), \theta\sim$Gamma($n+1, b$), $\theta>0$. Want to find Bayes estimate assuming the loss function $L(\theta, d(x)) = (\theta-d(x))^2.$ The Gamma has a shape parameter $n+1$ and scale paramter $b$

As we know the posterior distribution is proportional to the prior and the likelihood function: $$\tau(\theta|x) \propto \tau(\theta) \cdot \tau(x|\theta) = \theta e^{-\theta/b} \cdot \mathbb{I} (\max_{1\le i\le n} x_i \le \theta).$$ I am not sure if I can call this exponential($\theta$) so that the Bayes estimate becomes the mean of $\tau(\theta|x)$ which is $1/\theta.$ However, I think I'm missing something about $\mathbb{I} (\max_{1\le i \le n} x_i).$ Help is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is b?  Bayes estimate of _what_  theta?  b?  Both?  What is L, a loss function?  What's a?  What's τ()?

Comment: It's somewhat clearer, yes.  But is there a reason to use tau over the more standard P?

b is a shape parameter, but is it known/fixed?

I personally would not call the estimator minimizing an expected posterior loss a "Bayes estimator" -- I would reserve that for estimating the entire distribution.  Picking the best choice is a decision theory thing.

It's a truncated exponential.  Taking the mean of the values gets you what you want (mean is always what minimizes that loss function).

Comment: No reason. Just choice of notations. b is fixed.